# VID/PID возможно ли имитировать другое значение "на лету"?

Tags: c#, железо

Есть некий девайс, что-то вроде звуковой карты. Мне нужно изменить VID/PID девайса на другой. Я понимаю что они прошиты физически и их без перепрошивки чипа на девайсе не изменить их.

Интересует возможно ли изменять "на лету" VID/PID при запросе системы? То есть когда дается запрос на VID/PID конкретного устройства, что бы система видела то значение, которое мне нужно. 
Какими-то прерываниями системы, виртуальным устройством сигналы с которого будут перенаправлятся на нужное или еще как-то?

Возможно ли это в принципе?

Видел информацию что это возможно сделать как-то с помощью devcon ( devcon's sethwid ) но без деталей.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Один из вариантов, правда, очень напутанный и с использованием Linux

1. Патчим usbipd, чтобы он подменял vid и pid нужного устройства
2. При помощи него пробрасываем устройство по сети на машину с Windows.

Comment: Сильно муторно и создаст черезчур большую задержку в работе с устройством. =( Но спасибо все равно.

Comment: @Andrew да как-то задержек особых незаметно - USB2.0 помещается в гигабитную сеть с двойным запасом.

Comment: угу, только в гигабитную сеть если подключено кабелем, а не вайфайкой :) А в любой вайфайке скорость куда ниже + еще и падение пинга в 2-3 раза на долю секунды каждые несколько секунд :)

Comment: @ Ну, фокус можно провернуть и на локальной машине, используя виртуалки. Если сильно нужно.